# SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xe2

Tags: python, python-2.7

I receive this error:

```
SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xe2
```

when running the following code:

```
verse = "If you can keep your head when all about you\n  Are losing theirs and blaming it on you,\nIf you can trust yourself when all men doubt you,\n  But make allowance for their doubting too;\nIf you can wait and not be tired by waiting,\n  Or being lied about, don’t deal in lies,\nOr being hated, don’t give way to hating,\n  And yet don’t look too good, nor talk too wise:"
  
print(verse)
```

I am using python 2.7 and included `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-`

Comment: Don't use Python 2.7. Python 3 strings are Unicode. You'll find a *lot* of duplicate questions, and the real solution is to avoid the EOL language

Comment: As for this specific error, it's probably due to invisible characters in the string, perhaps non-breaking spaces? A newline is `0x10`, not `0xE2` and needs only a single byte in UTF8.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos it is `’` (not the ASCII `'`) in `don’t`

Comment: @Błotosmętek good catch. Could be worse - I once found a question about a full-length comma that looked *exactly* the same as a space-and-comma

Comment: In Python 2 you have mark unicode string with a `u` like `u"abc..."`.